# AmCharts - OLHC chart not visible

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts

Here is my StockGraph object:

```
"stockGraphs": [ {
        "id": "g1",
        "title": "someText",
        "precision": 2,
        "openField": "open",
        "closeField": "close",
        "highField": "high",
        "lowField": "low",
        "valueField": "close",
        "lineColor": "#00e673",
        "fillColors": "#00e673",
        "negativeLineColor": "#db4c3c",
        "negativeFillColors": "#db4c3c",
        "type": "olhc",
        "compareable": true,
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "balloonText": "open: [[open]]\nclose: [[close]]\nhigh: [[high]]\nclose: [[close]]",
        "fillAlphas": 0.6
      } ],
```

When I replace the type with candlestick or line, it displays perfectly. But when I set it to olhc, nothing is displayed. chart cursors are visible thought. may be the chart is drawn but not visible for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`type`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#type) needs to be o**h**lc. Swap the letters and it will work. Note that when comparing datasets, the compared graphs won't support ohlc as [`compareGraphType`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#compareGraphType) only supports line, column, step and smoothedLine.